# Seeing composition table

Tags: group-theory

Let p > 2 be any prime number. The non-zero integers modulo p form a group of order p - 1 with respect to multiplication modulo p.

$$ [a][b] = [ab] = ab (mod p) $$

denoted Gp.

The identity is obviously the residue class [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoyOm.jpg), in but in order to prove the existence of inverses one needs the following result from number theory:

if p and q are relatively prime numbers then there exists interfers k and m such that kp + mq = 1. since p is a prime number, if:

$$ [q] \neq [0] $$

then q relatively prime to p and for some k and m

$$ [m][q] = [1] - [k][p] = [1] $$

Hence

$$ [q]^{-1} = [m] $$

however I can't see the law of composition in it's multiplication table, where the product of the ith and jth elements are (i, j) in each element:

[image: Composition table]

Comment: Everything you're writing looks right (except you mean $[q]^{-1}=[m]$, not $[q^{-1}]=[m]$), but ... what is your _question_?

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6 appear in each column and each row, each exactly once.

Comment: My question is if you could crunch some numbers out to show me how the elements in the table are made. The only constraint I was given is that p > 2, m, q and k haven't been defined.

Comment: The $(i,j)$ entry is $\ ij\ {\rm mod}\ 7,\,$ i.e. is the multiplication table for arithmetic mod $\,7\ \ $

Comment: Thanks, I have now seen that the the numbers for when xy > 7, the greatest common divisor is chosen as it's place. Thus the modulo is displayed in the composition table.